# Convert the http request to json

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

How do I convert the response from [this url](http://wcf.builderscopilot.com/Mobileservice.svc/TProspectReport?Neigh=R1_D1_C295_N319&TDate=3M) to json?  I get `valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key ANeighborhood.'` error due to escape sequences in `NSLog(@"array 5656 = %@", array);` in the following code Here's what I tried.

```
 NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

    NSError *error;
    NSString *jsonString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];

    if(!error)
    {
        NSData *jsonData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:Nil];

        NSDictionary *dict = [jsonDict valueForKey:@"ProspectReportResult"];

        NSString *jsonString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", dict];

        NSLog(@"String 444 = %@", jsonString);

        NSString *jsonString1=[jsonString stringByAppendingFormat:@"%s","]"];
        NSString *jsonString12=@"[";
        NSString *jsonString2=[jsonString12 stringByAppendingString: jsonString1];
        NSString *jsonString22=@"}{";
        jsonString2= [jsonString2 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:jsonString22 withString:@"}][{"];

        NSLog(@"String 999 = %@", jsonString2);

        //jsonString2 = [jsonString2 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\" withString:@""];
        NSArray *array12=[jsonString2 componentsSeparatedByString: @"]"];
        NSLog(@"Aray2323 = %@", array12);
        for(NSString* str in array12)
        {
            NSString *str1=[str stringByAppendingFormat:@"%s","]"];
            str1 = [str1 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\" withString:@""];
            NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObject:str1];
            NSLog(@"array 5656 = %@", array);

            for (NSDictionary *dict in array) {
                NSLog(@"Dictionary :%@",dict);
                prospect = [[ProspectData alloc]init];
                [prospectArray addObject:prospect];
                prospect.ANeighborhood= (NSString*)[dict valueForKey:@"ANeighborhood"];
                prospect.BClientName= (NSString*)[dict valueForKey:@"BClientName"];
                prospect.CSoldStatus=(NSString*)[dict valueForKey:@"CSoldStatus"];
                prospect.DFirstVisit=(NSString*)[dict valueForKey:@"DFirstVisit"];
                prospect.ELastVisit=(NSString*)[dict valueForKey:@"ELastVisit"];
                prospect.FNoOfVisit=(NSString*)[dict valueForKey:@"FNoOfVisit"];
                prospect.GTypeOfLead=(NSString*)[dict valueForKey:@"GTypeOfLead"];
                prospect.HPurchRealtor=(NSString*)[dict valueForKey:@"HPurchRealtor"];
                prospect.IClientSource=(NSString*)[dict valueForKey:@"IClientSource"];

            }

        }
        //[self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
        self.tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    }
```

Comment: Go to json.org and study the JSON syntax.  The outermost structure is an "object" (dictionary), not an array.  You cannot handle JSON by simply copying examples off the internet, you must *understand* it.

Comment: Actually I think the JSON value under `ProspectReportResult` key is invalid. It should be an array of dicts `[{..},{..},..]` separated by `,`. You should fix the response.

Comment: @Amar that's what i was trying to achieve by using NSString class reference. I argued enough to fix the response

Comment: @user3244372 Modifying the json response will have performance issues in your app. It is not advisable. Better to fix this from server's end.

Answer (score 2):

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
```

Comment: +1, Some explanation will be useful, since OP looks like new user.

Comment: NSJSONSerialization is Apple's built-in JSON parser, and using it as @iDev suggested will convert well formed JSON into either an NSDictionary or an NSArray with a matching structure to the JSON file. Place a breakpoint just after this line, then hover on dictionary until an eye appears, click on that and the console will show you what was captured.

Comment: yes.. i need some explanation.. how will I get value for 'ProspectReportResult' from this line?

Comment: @Amar will you please help me with this?

Comment: @user3244372 Were you able to use this code? If Yes, all you now need to do is call `NSDictionary *prospectReportResultDict = [dictionary valueForKey:@"ProspectReportResult"];` and you will get the required dictionary from the response.

Comment: @Amar I tried this, but still get the data "WITH ESCAPE SEQUENCES". Hence I get a crash which says : this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key ANeighborhood.

Comment: @user3244372 Can you try once with `NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];`? Pass `options` as `NSJSONReadingAllowFragments`